# TypeError: 'apartment' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the problem I am trying to solve.
Create a class called apartment with attributes flatnumber,owner name,electricity bill amount.Create another class apartment_demo with def init(self):pass to create a method getSecondMinBill that takes the list of objects and gives the second minimum electricity bill as output.

```
Input:3(no.of objects to be created)
1000
Hari
5000
1001
Hena
5002
1002
Harsha
5001
Output:5001
```

This is my code

```
class apartment:
    def __init__(self,flat_no,owner_name,ele_bill):
        self.flatnumber=flat_no
        self.owner_name=owner_name
        self.ele_bill_amount=ele_bill

class apartment_demo(apartment):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_second_min(self):
        list=[]
        a=int(input())
        for i in range(a):
            f=int(input())
            o=str(input())
            e=int(input())
            list.append(apartment(f,o,e))
        l=len(list)
        #print(self.ele_bill_amount for i in list)
        for i in range(0,l):
            for j in range(0,l-i-1):
                if list[j][2]>list[j+1][2]:
                    temp=list[j][2]
                    list[j][2]=list[j+1][2]
                    list[j+1][2]=temp
        print(list[1][2])
        #print("Flat no:",self.flatnumber,"Owner 
        #name:",self.owner_name,"Ele.bill:",self.ele_bill_amount)

a=apartment_demo()
a.get_second_min()
```

This is the error I am getting

```
if list[j][2]>list[j+1][2]:
TypeError: 'apartment' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `list[j]` returns an instance of your `apartment` class; let's call this `apt1`. What then would you want to return when you request for the value of `apt1[2]`? Oh and try not to name your variables the same as builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was very hard to decipher, so I cleaned it up a bit to be more readable. First, you shouldn't use restricted words as variable names such as `List` as this could cause some issues. Next, there is no need to inherit the `apartment` class as you aren't using any methods from it. Also, you don't have to cast your name input to a string as the input is already a string. Finally, your method of finding the second largest bill was hard to read, so I created a different method. Below is the code.

```
    def __init__(self,flat_no,owner_name,ele_bill):
        self.flatnumber=flat_no
        self.owner_name=owner_name
        self.ele_bill_amount=ele_bill

class apartment_demo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_second_min(self):
        obj_list=[]
        bill_list =[]
        a=int(input())
        for i in range(a):
            f=int(input())
            o=input()
            e=int(input())
            obj_list.append(apartment(f,o,e))
        for i in obj_list:
          bill_list.append(i.ele_bill_amount)
        max_bill = max(bill_list)
        while True:
          bill_list.remove(max_bill)
          if max_bill not in bill_list:
            second_largest = max(bill_list)
            print("The second largest bill is " + str(second_largest))
            break
        #print("Flat no:",self.flatnumber,"Owner 
        #name:",self.owner_name,"Ele.bill:",self.ele_bill_amount)

a=apartment_demo()
a.get_second_min()
```

What's happening here is that I append each object to the `obj_list` which I renamed from `list` to be more clear. Then, I created a new list to store the bills of each apartment which I called `bill_list`. From there, I used the `max()` function which takes a list as an input and returns the largest value in that list. Then, I used a while loop to remove the largest bill using `.remove(max_bill)`. Then I check if the largest bill is still in the list using `if max_bill not in bill_list:`. If this condition is true, I just call `max()` again to return the next max value in the list. This will be your second largest bill. If the condition is false, the while loop iterates again and removes the largest bill.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below, with minimal changes to your code -

```
class apartment():
    def __init__(self,flat_no,owner_name,ele_bill):
        self.flatnumber=flat_no
        self.owner_name=owner_name
        self.ele_bill_amount=ele_bill

    def getAttr(self):
        return [self.flatnumber, self.owner_name, self.ele_bill_amount]

class apartment_demo(apartment):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_second_min(self):
        print('inside')
        list=[]
        a=int(input('Num: '))
        for i in range(a):
            f=int(input('flat no: '))
            o=str(input('owner name: '))
            e=int(input('elect bill: '))
            a = apartment(f,o,e)
            list.append(a.getAttr())
        l=len(list)
        #print(self.ele_bill_amount for i in list)
        for i in range(0,l):
            for j in range(0,l-i-1):
                if list[j][2]>list[j+1][2]:
                    temp=list[j][2]
                    list[j][2]=list[j+1][2]
                    list[j+1][2]=temp
        print(list[1][2])
        #print("Flat no:",self.flatnumber,"Owner 
        #name:",self.owner_name,"Ele.bill:",self.ele_bill_amount)

a=apartment_demo()
a.get_second_min()
```